# Separate big array from main component to a new file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in the front end world, and I currently working on Angular project with typescript, and I created an array in order to assign to an object, so I have something like this in my `TS` component:

```
    formOptions = []

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formOptions = [{
            id: 1,
            description: 'First name'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            description: 'Middle name'
          }, {
            id: 3,
            description: 'Last name'
          }...etc
        }
```

As you can see the array it's going to be supper big, is there a way to move the array to separate file, then import it and just assign the object? If so, where is the common path to save this path of files and what extension I should use for it?

Comment: You can store this array as a return from a function that resides in other .ts file and exported. Then you can import this function and call it to assign the array content to new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the array in a separate `.json` file. Then use fetch to load the file and parse the JSON. JSON is Javascript Object Notation and it will take an array (or object) exactly as you have it laid out in your code.

```
[{
            id: 1,
            description: 'First name'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            description: 'Middle name'
          }, {
            id: 3,
            description: 'Last name'
          }...etc
        }]
```

The [first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) at MDN does exactly what I describe.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I think the Felnyr on comments above is a better, because you do not need to parse the object.

Comment: There are a lot of considerations. It is still being parsed, just at a different point in the JavaScript lifecycle. On the other hand this fetch method, if the array is really large, may help with page load times since it can be done asynchronously.